# Is text messaging required, if account information is lost for both Facebook profile and associated email account?

Tags: facebook, account-management, sms

Suppose a user has lost their login information for their Facebook account and their email account at the same time; can this user regain access to their account using a regular land-line, or does it require the number of a phone with text messaging?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will also let you back in via a "Trusted Friends" feature, no text messaging required.

> Trusted friends are friends you can reach out to if you ever get locked out of your Facebook account (ex: you turn on login approvals and then lose your phone, you forget your Facebook password and can’t get into your login email account to receive a password reset). If you get locked out, we’ll send each of your trusted friends a security code. All you need to do is call your friends and collect the codes.
>
> You’ll only need 3 codes to get back into your account, but we recommend picking 5 trusted friends so you have back-up. Your trusted friends should be people you can easily call and who are likely to respond to you quickly.
>
> You can pick your trusted friends from your Security Settings page.

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=119897751441086#What-are-trusted-friends?